# PowerShell script to zip files inside many folders recursive

Tags: powershell, recursion, zip, powershell-2.0

I would like to go inside every folder recursive in some location,
for example: C:\Logs and zip files to the same folder.

I need to skip every .zip file. I don't know how to make my script to do this:

```
function New-Zip
{
    param([string]$zipfilename)
    set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
    (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false
}
function Add-Zip
{
    param([string]$zipfilename)

    if(-not (test-path($zipfilename)))
    {
        set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
        (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false
    }

    $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)

    foreach($file in $input)
    {
            $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
            Start-sleep -milliseconds 500
    }
}
$targetFolder = 'C:\Logs'
$now = Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00
$days = 5
$lastWrite = $now.AddDays(-$days)

Get-ChildItem $targetFolder -Recurse -Exclude *zip* | Where-Object { $_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo] } | ForEach-Object {
    If ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $lastWrite)
    {
        $_ | New-Zip $($targetFolder + $_.Name + ".zip" )
        $_ | Add-Zip $($targetFolder + $_.Name + ".zip" )
    }
}
```

Comment: The `CopyHere` method is an interactive shell function that is not designed for automation (e.g., no error checking). I would strongly recommend using a command-line tool such as `7z.exe` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently excluding any file or folder that contains the phrase 'zip' in its name as you have a wildcard either side of it:

```
Get-ChildItem $targetFolder -Recurse -Exclude *zip*
```

To exclude zip files you just need to update your `Exclude` statement so that it matches only the zip file extension:

```
Get-ChildItem $targetFolder -Recurse -Exclude *.zip
```

Comment: I have corrected it. I still dont know how to go inside every directory inside folder and zip file in here.